# Alternative to excel for data dictionaries etc

Tags: excel, git, configuration

In our current application we are currently using excel for some semi-complex configuration. We are using excel, because:

- The domain expert knows it well
- It supports lookups / data validation / some normalization
- In some cases we also us it in test cases to validate some computatios

Now that's all great, but we are hitting major issue with branching/comparing/merging.

I've looked into different options:

- Araxis can compare, but not merge (I doubt any tool can)
- Beyond compare doesn't really work with sheets in a usable way
- we didn't manage to setup xls2text correctly / it works only from command line / again no merge
- Saving as fods (libre office) produces an xml which is hard to interpret in diff

  - using google spreadsheet would make a mess trying to develop on parallel branches

Is there any other relatively simple option?

Edit: i found this visual compare which is free and seems to work well... of course we need to merge manually, but at least we can see the changes
https://github.com/kokichi88/ExcelDiff_MergeTool

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a better way to store and/or manipulate (and report upon) your data, compared to your current method of Excel, then ***Microsoft Access*** is the obvious choice.

### Microsoft Access:

- is as easy to learn as Excel *(easier if you already know as Excel)*
- is fast & efficient
- is powerful; capable of handling *huge* amounts of data
- is completely integratable with Excel and other MS Office apps
- is interfacable with countless other applications
- has a huge following online with many excellent reputable dedicated forums
- is  efficient yet scaleable
- is inexpensive, free, or *already included* with your existing Office installation

Comment: `•is inexpensive, free, or already included with your existing Office installation`. MS Access is not available if you have Office standard. With Office professional, it is readily available.

Comment: doesn't solve the key problem (branching/merging) and is not available on mac. Now, libreoffice database could also serve as a front end, but the backend db would need to be clear text and support jdbc...